# Django sqlite development to production

Tags: django, git, sqlite, development-environment

I am having trouble understanding how to synchronise my development and production environments.

I have a production and development branch in git, with the production branch being of course what the server's copy is.

My sqlite database is currently under version control (which I now gather it shouldn't be, however I am not sure how I would sync my copies of the project if it wasn't?)

When I want to make a change I commit and push the server's copy to production and then I pull that down to my local machine.  I then make a change (which can include database changes), but then in terms of getting those changes back into production, I am not sure how to get the changes back onto my server without potentially overwriting changes that have occurred on the server since I started the change?

How can I handle local changes to the database when changes may also have occurred on the server at the same time?  I have been searching for a while and thought that maybe South was for that kind of problem but I gather that it is an old solution.

Thanks for your help

Comment: why would you want to migrate the development data to production database? Anyway, get an sqldump of your local database and then update your production db with sql import

Comment: I am storing things like email template text in one of my database tables.  Also I have scoring information in another table (values for scoring a survey).  Is this all bad practice too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's definitively a wrong way. You should never share a database between environments. However, it is a good approach to use the same *database engine* on the production and dev environment but it doesn't mean that you need to share a DB, in the case of sqlite3.

Many developers use sqlite3 on dev and other DB engines on the production. This is acceptable but it is not recommended, because of differences between database engines.

Comment: Goran lets just say that I have two seperate databases then - how do I keep their fields in sync?  If I add a model field in dev how can I automatically get that replicated in production?

Comment: You need to create a migration `python manage.py makemigrations` then add your migration to git and push. On the production just run `python manage.py migrate`. This is correct way.

Comment: find more about [Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/) on docs